# Appending objects to Python array becomes linearly slower as more items are added

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to python so forgive me if what I am doing is dumb.
I am trying to create a python array of numpy arrays of which each has a shape of (2000, 89401).
I have a total of 35 of these numpy arrays which I am trying to append to the python array.
Bellow is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import glob

data_filepath = []
for filename in glob.glob('*.npy'):
    data_filepath.append(filename)

LIST_SIZE = 2000
train_images  = []
train_labels = []
for i in range(len(data_filepath)):
    print("reading file" + data_filepath[i])
    train_images.append(np.load(data_filepath[i], encoding='latin1', allow_pickle=True)[0:LIST_SIZE])
    train_labels.append(np.ones((LIST_SIZE, 1)) * i)
```

I have added a line `print("reading file" + data_filepath[i])` to print a line in the terminal as the code runs, so I can see the speed of execution.
The first 4 numpy arrays are read almost immediately but as the execution progresses, it gets slower and slower. I put the program to run for 5 minutes and added 9 numpy arrays.
I emptied the python array in the for loop to see if the `append()` is the culprit:

```
.
.
.
for i in range(len(data_filepath)):
    print("reading file" + data_filepath[i])
    train_images.append(np.load(data_filepath[i], encoding='latin1', allow_pickle=True)[0:LIST_SIZE])
    train_labels.append(np.ones((LIST_SIZE, 1)) * i)
    train_images = []
    train_labels = []
```

And the code executed in mere seconds. How can I read my numpy arrays without this performance penalty?

Comment: I suppose garbage collection could help in the second case, is the memory consumption identical? Do you have enough RAM? This almost certainly has nothing to do with the list since it has very few elements. Also, how much memory do you have? How large is the loaded array before you take the first 2K subarrays? Because numpy indexing returns views, the whole loaded array stays in the memory.

Comment: How much RAM do you have, and what are the dtypes of these arrays? You're likely running out of memory.

Comment: I think you are correct, my 8GB memory gets full after the four numpy arrays are read, and then the execution hinders.

Comment: You are appending to a **list**

Answer (score 0):

My memory got full after loading the first few numpy arrays into the python list.
I was able to circumvent this problem by specifying `mmap_mode='r'` in the following function:

```
train_images.append(np.load(data_filepath[i], mmap_mode='r', encoding='latin1', allow_pickle=True)[0:LIST_SIZE])
```

`mmap_mode` tells numpy to open the `.npy` as read only and not load everything into memory.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html#numpy.memmap:

"Memory-mapped files are used for accessing small segments of large files on disk, without reading the entire file into memory. NumPy’s memmap’s are array-like objects. This differs from Python’s mmap module, which uses file-like objects."